# GKE - ErrImagePull pulling from Google Container Registry

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I have a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster which until recently was happily pulling private container images from a Google Container Registry bucket. I haven't changed anything, but now when I update my Kubernetes Deployments, it's unable to launch new pods, and I get the following events:

```
Normal   Pulling  14s                kubelet, <node-id>  pulling image "gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:latest"
Normal   Pulling  14s                kubelet, <node-id>  pulling image "gcr.io/<project-id>/backend:62d634e"
Warning  Failed   14s                kubelet, <node-id>  Failed to pull image "gcr.io/<project-id>/backend:62d634e": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unauthorized: authentication required
Warning  Failed   14s                kubelet, <node-id>  Error: ErrImagePull
Normal   Pulled   13s                kubelet, <node-id>  Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:latest"
Normal   Created  13s                kubelet, <node-id>  Created container
Normal   Started  13s                kubelet, <node-id>  Started container
Normal   BackOff  11s (x2 over 12s)  kubelet, <node-id>  Back-off pulling image "gcr.io/<project-id>/backend:62d634e"
Warning  Failed   11s (x2 over 12s)  kubelet, <node-id>  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

I've checked the following things, which all seem to be as they should:

- The containers and their tags actually exist, and are correct.
- The node pool / VM Instances for the GKE cluster have the `storage-ro` permission
- The Google Container Registry bucket and GKE cluster are in the same project

I've also tried disabling and re-enabling the container.googleapis.com and containerregistry.googleapis.com services, but that doesn't help.

The Google documentation for the Container Registry states:

> Kubernetes Engine clusters are automatically configured with access to
>   pull private images from the Container Registry in the same project.
>   You do not need to follow additional steps to configure authentication
>   if the registry and the cluster are in the same Cloud project.

But this doesn't seem to be the case.

Can anyone shed additional light on what might be going on? Or additional steps to try?

Comment: Hey Jason, I am facing the same issue. Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the issue turned out to be that the node pools generated by a minimal spec file are missing the oauth2 scopes that give access to the registry. Adding

```
nodePools:
  config:
    oauthScopes:
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
```

to my spec fixed things. I *think* it's the `devstorage` scope that's the important one, but I'm not sure since I just copy-pasted the whole list of scopes from the spec the web console generates.

Comment: I think it is just `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only` needed as well. At least that was all I added to the service account I was using.

Comment: "I just copy-pasted the whole list of scopes from the spec the web console generates" how did you do it?

Comment: Go to the "Create cluster" wizard, then look for the "Equivalent REST" button at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: If this weren't a post from last year I'd assume it's a GKE version issue but I don't understand why I didn't need these scopes before in other clusters in other projects. I'm baffled.

Comment: Oh wait nevermind I just realized it's because I already have those oauth scopes there in the cluster config. They already exist for each node pool and therefore this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, this turned out to be tricky, but the cause was this:

I used Terraform to set the service account for the nodes in the GKE cluster, but instead of using the `email` output of the `google_service_account` resource to specify the service account, I used the `unique_id` output instead. This was accepted fine by both Terraform and the Google Cloud API.

When Kubernetes (and other things) was trying to access the internal metadata API on each node to get an token it could use, it was receiving a response of `Service account is invalid/disabled` and a 403 status.

Recreating the node pool with the correctly specified service account fixed the problem.

Comment: For me, turned out that my terraform template google_bcuket_acl was actually REMOVING the ACL for the service account, even though no reference to it was made anywhere in the template. Dropping this here in case anyone falls into the same trap.

Comment: My is set to the default account so it's not this.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, setting the correct oAuth scopes didn't work. So I just configured it for any other private repository by adding `imagePullSecrets` to my Pod Spec.

[Kubernetes Docs | Pull an Image from a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

### Sample Script to generate registry credentials in pipeline

You could do this manually as well if you don't manage your infrastructure as code right now.

```sh
# Setup registry credentials so we can pull images from gcr
gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://gcr.io

kubectl create secret generic regcred \
    --namespace=development \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson="${HOME}/.docker/config.json" \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson \
    --output yaml --dry-run | kubectl apply -f - # create or update if already created
```

### Sample Deployment File

(Don't mind all the substitutions). That isn't relevant. Just check the last line of the `yaml` file.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: ${NAMESPACE}
  name: ${PROJECT_PREFIX}-${PROJECT_TYPE}-${PROJECT_NAME}
  labels:
    name: ${PROJECT_PREFIX}-${PROJECT_TYPE}-${PROJECT_NAME}
spec:
  replicas: ${REPLICA_COUNT}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: ${PROJECT_PREFIX}-${PROJECT_TYPE}-${PROJECT_NAME}
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: ${PROJECT_PREFIX}-${PROJECT_TYPE}-${PROJECT_NAME}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ${PROJECT_PREFIX}-${PROJECT_TYPE}-${PROJECT_NAME}
          image: gcr.io/${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}/${PROJECT_TYPE}-${PROJECT_NAME}:${GITHUB_SHA}
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: ${PORT}
              protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /${PROJECT_NAME}/v1/health
              port: ${PORT}
            initialDelaySeconds: 0
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: ${RESOURCES_CPU_REQUEST}
              memory: ${RESOURCES_MEMORY_REQUEST}
            limits:
              cpu: ${RESOURCES_CPU_LIMIT}
              memory: ${RESOURCES_MEMORY_LIMIT}
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: ${NODE_ENV}
            - name: PORT
              value: '${PORT}'
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when I created a cluster with terraform. Firstly, I only specified `service_account` in `node_config` so node pool was made with too small OAuth scopes. Explicitly write both `service_account` and `oauth_scope` like below, nodes are able to pull images from private GCR repositories.

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_preemptible_nodes" {
  node_config {
    service_account = "${google_service_account.gke_nodes.email}"

    oauth_scopes = [
      "storage-ro",
      "logging-write",
      "monitoring"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @translucens, we ran into this problem and your answer solved it!

Comment: How did you specify a service account? I have the same problem, but the above did not solve it. I use the project_no-compute service account.

Comment: @Mike If `service_account = "${google_service_account.gke_nodes.email}"` removed, your service account (default compute service account) will be used.

Comment: What's wrong with using the default service account? That has worked for me for years now so this isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the node events for the actual error.
For me it said:

```
Failed to pull image "gcr.io/project/image@sha256:c8e91af54fc17faa1c49d2a05def5cbabf8f0a67fc558eb6cbca138061b8400a":
 rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error pulling image configuration: unknown blob
```

That turned out to be the image being gone or corrupted.
After pushing the image again it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For whom using `terraform`

1. Go find your node pools yaml
2. Adding a service account for it with `roles/artifactregistry.reader` or `roles/storage.objectViewer`
   EX.

```
resource "google_service_account" "kubernetes" {
  account_id = "kubernetes"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "allow_image_pull" {
  project = "any-projectname"
  role   = "roles/artifactregistry.reader"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.kubernetes.email}"
}
```

3. within the `node_config` context put the service account there
   EX.

```
service_account = google_service_account.kubernetes.email
```