# ImagePullBackOff from GCR.io registry on Kubernetes Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

**Kubernetes** is unable to launch **container** using **image** from private gcr.io **container registry**.
The error says "ImagePullBackOff".
Both Kubernetes and Container registry are in the same Google Cloud project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was with permissions.
It turns out that a **service account** that is used to launch **Kubernetes** needs to have reading permissions for *Google Cloud Storage* (this is important as the **registry** itself is using **buckets** to store images)

Exact details [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#granting_users_and_other_projects_access_to_a_registry)

Comment: Specifically `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only` by the looks of it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54622379/2387626