# ImagePullBackOff on GKE with Private Google Cloud Repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I am creating a deployment in GKE with a following (standard) deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: eu.gcr.io/xxxx-xxx/api:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "320Mi"
            cpu: "100m"
          limits:
            memory: "450Mi"
            cpu: "150m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5010
```

However, for some reason GKE complains about a permission issue. The containers are in container registry of the same project and PRIVATE, but as far as I am aware if it with a GCP project GKE should be able to have access. The GKE cluster is vpc-native (if that might make a difference) as that is the only difference I can think of compared a cluster I used to run with the same containers and installers.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From                                                     Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----                                                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled  34m                    default-scheduler                                        Successfully assigned default/api-deployment-f68977b84-fmhdx to gke-gke-dev-cluster-default-pool-6c6bb127-nw61
  Normal   Pulling    32m (x4 over 33m)      kubelet, gke-gke-dev-cluster-default-pool-6c6bb127-nw61  pulling image "eu.gcr.io/xxxx-xxx/api:latest"
  Warning  Failed     32m (x4 over 33m)      kubelet, gke-gke-dev-cluster-default-pool-6c6bb127-nw61  Failed to pull image "eu.gcr.io/xxxx-xxx/api:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for eu.gcr.io/xxxx-xxx/api, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
  Warning  Failed     32m (x4 over 33m)      kubelet, gke-gke-dev-cluster-default-pool-6c6bb127-nw61  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    32m (x6 over 33m)      kubelet, gke-gke-dev-cluster-default-pool-6c6bb127-nw61  Back-off pulling image "eu.gcr.io/xxxx-xxx/api:latest"
  Warning  Failed     3m59s (x131 over 33m)  kubelet, gke-gke-dev-cluster-default-pool-6c6bb127-nw61  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Do I need to add ImageSecrets as well for GKE clusters with the google cloud repository or might there be another problem?

The GKE cluster was created using TerraForm with the following gke.tf for GKE

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name = "gke-${terraform.workspace}-cluster"
  zone = "${var.region}-b"

  additional_zones = [
    "${var.region}-c",
    "${var.region}-d",
  ]

  # minimum kubernetes version for master
  min_master_version = "${var.min_master_version}"
  # version for the nodes. Should equal min_master_version on create
  node_version       = "${var.node_version}"
  initial_node_count = "${var.gke_num_nodes[terraform.workspace]}"
  network            = "${var.vpc_name}"
  subnetwork         = "${var.subnet_name}"

  addons_config {

    http_load_balancing {
      disabled = false  # this is the default
    }

    horizontal_pod_autoscaling {
      disabled = false
    }

    kubernetes_dashboard {
      disabled = false
    }
  }

  # vpc-native network
  ip_allocation_policy {
#    use_ip_aliases = true
  }

  master_auth {
    username = "${var.gke_master_user}"
    password = "${var.gke_master_pass}"
  }

  node_config {
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
    ]

    labels = {
      env = "${var.gke_label[terraform.workspace]}"
    }

    disk_size_gb = 10
    machine_type = "${var.gke_node_machine_type}"
    tags         = ["gke-node"]
  }
}
```

running gcloud gcloud container clusters describe [CLUSTER] gives

```
nodePools:
- config:
    diskSizeGb: 10
    diskType: pd-standard
    imageType: COS
    labels:
      env: dev
    machineType: n1-standard-1
    metadata:
      disable-legacy-endpoints: 'true'
    oauthScopes:
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
    serviceAccount: default
```

so devstorage.read_only seems to be there

Answer (score 8):

Are your GKE cluster node pools configured with the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only` OAuth scope?

To check you can run `gcloud container clusters describe [CLUSTER NAME]`: scopes are listed under the `oauthScopes` property. Or check your node pool details at the GCP dashboard:

[image: GKE node pool OAuth scopes]

`Storage` should be enabled.

Comment: Thanks Aleksi, I have added my output to the question. Storage seems enabled to me. I also have the same screenshot as you have.

Comment: Ok, so we can rule that out. Would you mind attaching your terraform configuration? One of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52572227/1763012) might be relevant to your case also.

Comment: I have added the .tf file as well. I came across the thread you referred, but could not resolve it yet.

Comment: Hmm.. one more thing you might want to check is that the service account used by GKE nodes (most likely `Compute Engine default service account`) has correct permissions.

Comment: I am not sure how to see which permissions it has? I can see it for the IAM accounts, but not the default service account

Comment: Try `gcloud projects get-iam-policy [PROJECT ID]`; that shows each user and service account along their roles.

Comment: it replies etag: ACAB

Comment: Oh? It should reply with a list of bindings. You can also check service account roles via the web UI, at `https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=[PROJECT ID]`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use GCR, the nodes will need to run with service accounts and OAuth scopes that allow reading from cloud storage. There's some guidance for this topic here for example: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/access-scopes#service_account

Comment: the project is owned by a service account with Storage Admin permissions

Comment: The project owner's permissions do not guarantee that the cluster has correct permissions; we need to set cluster/node pool OAuth scopes separately.

Answer (score 0):

On addition to [Aleksi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763012/aleksi) comment and based on this documentation [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/get-iam-policy), you can also retrieve IAM policies for an individual service-account with:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy [SERVICE_ACCOUNT]
```