# GKE permission issue on gcr.io with service account based on terraform

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, service-accounts, terraform-provider-gcp

I am running into problems getting my containers from gcr.io

```
$ kubectl get po
NAME                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
api-deployment-74d8cf8768-x8bsk   0/2     ImagePullBackOff   4          2m43s
```

I create these deployments with the following yml file (deployment.yml)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: eu.gcr.io/api:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5060
```

from [GKE - ErrImagePull pulling from Google Container Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570027/gke-errimagepull-pulling-from-google-container-registry) I am guessing this is mostly a permission issue.

If I do

```
kubectl describe pod api-deployment-74d8cf8768-x8bsk
```

I get

```
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for eu.gcr.io/<project-dev>/api, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Permission denied for "latest" from request "/v2/<project-dev>/api/manifests/latest"
```

However, it is not clear how to set the appropriate service-account using terraform.

My set-up is as follows. I created a terraform administration project in GCP (terraform-admin) with a service account

```
tf-admin@terraform-admin.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

that contains the remote terraform state etc. The service-account has numerous roles such as:

```
Compute Network Admin
Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin
...
```

Then I create my actual development project project-dev (using the credentials of that service-account). In project-dev tf-admin@terraform-admin.iam.gserviceaccount.com is also an iam account 
as an

```
Owner
Compute Network Admin
Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin
```

However, it is not a service account. The only service account I see is

```
<project-dev-ID>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

which is a "Compute Engine default service account" that probably does not have the appropriate permissions. On project-dev I also have the container registry that contains my private containers.

As said, I create my GKE cluster using Terraform. Below is my (abbreviated) yml file.

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name     = "gke-cluster"
  location = "${var.region}-b"

  node_locations = [
    "${var.region}-c",
    "${var.region}-d",
  ]

  node_version       = var.node_version
  initial_node_count = 3
  network            = var.vpc_name
  subnetwork         = var.subnet_name

  addons_config {

    horizontal_pod_autoscaling {
      disabled = false
    }

  }

  master_auth {
    username = 'user'
    password = 'password'
  }

  node_config {

    # I HAVE TRIED ADDING THIS, BUT IT RESULT IN AN ERROR
    # Error: googleapi: Error 400: The user does not have access to service account 
    # service_account = "tf-admin@terraform-admin.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
    ]

    labels = {
      env = var.gke_label["${terraform.workspace}"]
    }

    disk_size_gb = 10
    machine_type = var.gke_node_machine_type
    tags         = ["gke-node"]
  }
}
```

Now, should I try (and if so, how) to add my tf-admin service account as a service account in project-dev or should I add a specific service account (again, how?) to the project-dev for kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default compute service account `<projectID>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` which does have all the required permissions to access GCR. Just make sure you use the default scopes for the cluster or make sure the gcr scopes are enabled along with storage read permissions.

Alternatively, you can use Terraform to create a service account with sufficient permissions (such as the storage viewer role) and then assign that service account to the node pool. In this case, you'll want to set the oauth_scopes to cloud_platform to ensure the scopes don't interfere with the IAM permissions.

You can view the default GKE scopes [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/set-service-account#--scopes)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by using the default compute-service account. I can see that service account and it has the role "editor". However, how do I know that is used what is used. I have edited my question with more details

Comment: you can't assign the `tf-admin@terraform-admin.iam.gserviceaccount.com` service account to the cluster in a different account. In your TF, replace it with `325667821671-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: Here https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#granting_users_and_other_projects_access_to_a_registry it is claimed GKE can access any gcr.io in the same project by default. It does not seem to do so.

Comment: yes, by default, assuming it is using the default scopes and the default service account. Once your cluster is created, is it using the default service account and the default scopes?

Comment: I don't know, but so if I remove service-account and oauth-scopes it should, I guess? Let me try that first and then using the service account + oauth scopes setup.

Comment: If you do not know which SA is at fault, please go to logging and search with protoPayload.status.message="PERMISSION_DENIED"  as an example. That should bring you closer to the culprit